# Javac does not create Main Class Reference

Tags: java, hadoop, netbeans, jar

I am trying to package up some java code which has references to the Hadoop API for java.  I am writing the code on my PC and moving it to a CentOS VM and then compiling it.

For some reason when I run the javac command and then un-jar the product file my `./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file does not have a line which defines the main class such as "Main-Class: folder1.folder2.file".  I believe this is why I am getting a "no main manifest attribute when trying to run Hadoop.jar".

Just to step through the process I have the code written using netbeans and import the Hadoop API .jar file.  After saving I upload Hadoop.java (this is the only file with code other than the Hadoop API) file to the VM in the `/usr/dan` directory.

From `/usr/dan` I run `javac -classpath /usr/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar -d ./Hadoop ./Hadoop.java` there aren't any errors displayed.

I then use `jar cvf ./Hadoop.jar -c ./Hadoop/` to create the jar file.  There aren't any errors displayed.

I then try to run the jar file with `java -jar Hadoop.jar` and get the error.

Is the only important file I need to upload to the VM the .java file?  I have the Hadoop API jar file in `/usr/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar`?

Once I execute the javac command the API is included in the .class file and I no longer need `/usr/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar`, correct? Or does this file need to be retained in a certain path relative to the .jar file?

What are the possible reasons the manifest file would not have a Main method defined in it?

Much appreciation for any help, I've been racking my brain on this all weekend.

EDIT:

By default the manifest include nearly empty, as stated here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html.  I can easily add an entry to the manifest file with the `m` flag.  I based my usage off of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html.  It seemed to me that this was something which had to be done after the jar file was created, but just adding the `m` flag with the appropriate components when initially jarring the file will do the trick in one shot.

Comment: I have no idea of hadoop, but if you create your jar through the `jar` command and want additional manifest entries (such as `Main-Class`), you'd need to use the `m` option (`jar cmf manifest-file jar-file content-files`) with a suitable manifest file (which can contain plain manifest entry lines).

Comment: I'm sorry if I do not understand, but is it always necessary to explicitly add a Main-Class entry to the manifest file?  Is there a way to have that entry populated in the initial jar process without having to go back and edit it?

Comment: @dst Thank you for the reply.  If you create an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your jar through the `jar` command and want additional manifest entries (such as `Main-Class`), you'd need to use the `m` option

```
jar cmf manifest-file jar-file content-files
```

with a suitable manifest file (which can contain plain manifest entry lines).

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop, it is not necessary that you need to have a Runnable Jar to execute. Hadoop come up with a utility for running Jars. You may use the following command for executing a Jar, which is not Runnable (Main class is missing in ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)

```
hadoop jar Hadoop.jar <PackageName>.<MainClassName> /input /output
```

If you don't have any packages use the following command

```
hadoop jar Hadoop.jar <MainClassName> /input /output
```